# Ubuntu 22.04 how to change postgresql default directory?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

In Ubuntu 22.04 i installed the postgresql server by default (apt install postgresql). The default location of the postgres configuration isn't in the same location of the data.

for example, you can find the postgresql.conf in the /etc/postgresql/14/main directory and the data is in /var/lib/postgresql/14/main directory.

If i want to configure replication the standby server dosn't find the .conf location, it says that the .conf file couldn't be find.
If i want to change the postgresql service so that the default location points to another directory, i cant find it.

After running "initdb -D/database/new_location"

How can i start the service pointing to the new DB in /database/new_location ?

I have tried to modify the service but no luck.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend that you stick with the layout that the Ubuntu packages suggest. It can be annoying, but it is not a problem. You could ask on DBA Stackexchange if you need help setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your respone. I finally created a service script that handles the startup

```
################################################################
# Note: changing PGDATA will typically require adjusting SELinux
# configuration as well.

# Note: do not use a PGDATA pathname containing spaces, or you will
# break postgresql-setup.
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL database server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=postgres
Group=postgres

# Note: avoid inserting whitespace in these Environment= lines, or you may
# break postgresql-setup.

# Location of database directory
Environment=PGDATA=/database/replica/

# Where to send early-startup messages from the server (before the logging
# options of postgresql.conf take effect)
# This is normally controlled by the global default set by systemd
# StandardOutput=syslog

# Disable OOM kill on the postmaster
OOMScoreAdjust=-1000

#ExecStartPre=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgresql95-check-db-dir ${PGDATA}
ExecStart=/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -w -t 300
ExecStop=/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl stop -D ${PGDATA} -s -m fast
ExecReload=/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_ctl reload -D ${PGDATA} -s

# Give a reasonable amount of time for the server to start up/shut down
TimeoutSec=300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```